# Cannot Looping Install Chocolatey Packages with Parameters

Tags: powershell, loops, parameters, chocolatey

I am creating [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) powershell script for my fresh Windows installation. 
My script is:

```
$dir = "$PSScriptRoot\packages.txt"
$pkgs = Get-Content -Path $dir
foreach ($string in $pkgs)
{
    choco install -y $string
}
```

In `packages.txt` i have my packages list. The list is look like this:

```
"notepadplusplus.install --x86"
"firefox"
...
```

If I use parameter it always give me error. The error messages is:

```
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Installing the following packages:
notepadplusplus.install --x86
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
notepadplusplus.install --x86 not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.
```

It didn't gave me error if I didn't use any parameter. But when I try to type it manually `choco install -y notepadplusplus.install --x86"` in console, the messages is:

```
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Installing the following packages:
notepadplusplus.install
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading notepadplusplus.install 7.8.2... 100%

notepadplusplus.install v7.8.2 [Approved]
notepadplusplus.install package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
Installing 32-bit notepadplusplus.install...
notepadplusplus.install has been installed.
```

As you can see, the parameters is not detected in the console, but it's still do what parameters says

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by change script to:

```
$dir = "$PSScriptRoot\packages.txt"
$pkgs = Get-Content -Path $dir
foreach ($string in $pkgs)
{
    $command = "choco install -y $string"
    iex $command
}
```

and delete `"` in `packages.txt`